# XSLT to convert fahrenheit to celsius

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and need to know how to convert a fahrenheit value to celsius value.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use formulas, providing that `x` is an XPath query to the fahrenheit value:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(x - 32) * 5 div 9" />
```

Also see [Math and XSLT](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/05/07/xsltmath.html).

I grabbed the conversion formula from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit)

Answer (score 3):

Having xml like

```
<degrees>
  <value>0</value>
</degrees>
```

You can use

```
<xsl:template match="degrees">
   <xsl:value-of select="(value - 32) div 1.8"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would start with the formula to do it, something like

```
Celsius = 100 /(212-32) * (Farenheit - 32)
```

Now, assuming you have an xml document which contains a bunch of F values which you want to convert - such as:

```
<temperatures>
  <temperature>10</temperature>
  <temperature>20</temperature>
  <temperature>30</temperature>
</temperatures>
```

you can use

```
<xsl:template match="temperatures">
   <xsl:value-of select="100 div (212-32) * (temperature - 32)"/>
</xsl:template>
```